# Adding parameters to $header links

Tags: theming

Is there a way we can specify which link to use to sort a drupal table, or atleast, specify some parameters to the header links?

To be more clear, my table uses the following link when I click on the headers to sort the table: http://mysite.com/node?sort=asc&order=Name

What I would like the header link to look like is this: http://mysite.com/node?nid=123&pager_element_id=3&sort=desc&order=Name

Is there any way we can give the parameters to the header links?

Answer (score 0):

The code that outputs the links for the table header is contained in [tablesort_header()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!tablesort.inc/function/tablesort_header/7).

```
$cell['data'] = l($cell['data'] . $image, $_GET['q'], array('attributes' => array('title' => $title), 'query' => array_merge($ts['query'], array('sort' => $ts['sort'], 'order' => $cell['data'])), 'html' => TRUE));
```

The function is called from [theme_table()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7), which is the theme function used to render a table.

What you can do is implementing your theme function that is then used to render the table your module is outputting. There isn't any other method, as `theme_table()` is not getting any parameter that changes the URL for the table header; as such, implementing `hook_preprocess_table()` would not achieve anything.

To implement a theme function, you need to declare it using [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'mymodule_table' => array(
      'variables' => array('header' => NULL, 'rows' => NULL, 'attributes' => array(), 'caption' => NULL, 'colgroups' => array(), 'sticky' => TRUE, 'empty' => ''),
    ),
  ); 
}
```

Once you declared the theme function, you can use it as you used `theme_table()`, simply replacing any call to `theme('table', /* the rest of the arguments */)` with `theme('mymodule_table', /* the rest of the arguments */)`. Notice that in `hook_theme()` the theme function is referred as mymodule_table, but the PHP function is `theme_mymodule_table()`.

The code you need for your theme function is the same used by `theme_table()`, except that instead of calling `tablesort_header()` it will call your own function.

```
foreach ($header as $cell) {
  $cell = tablesort_header($cell, $header, $ts); // Replace it with the call to your function.
  $output .= _theme_table_cell($cell, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, as I don't grasp the idea of implementing it in the theme function.